# Where do we find that the Torah is compared to a sea (yam)?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

Just need this for something I’m writing.

Comment: How do you know that such a comparison exists? Have you googled anything?

Comment: The Torah is compared to fire: "God came from Sinai ... and presented the fiery Torah to them with his right hand." [Deut. 33:2]

Comment: Top line here https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Chatam_Sofer_on_Chullin.89a?lang=bi

Comment: A point of comparison between Torah and water mentioned in *Shir HaShirim Rabba* (on verse 1:2) is that just as the sea covers the seabed, so too does the Torah cover over Israel's sins: "ומה מים מכסים ערותו של ים שנא' (ישעיה יא) כמים לים מכסה [מכסים] כך תורה מכסים ערותן של ישראל שנאמר (משלי י) ועל כל פשעים תכסה אהבה". This exposition cites *Mishlei* 10:12, and thus implicitly refers to the Torah as "love" (explicitly in *Tanna D'vei Eliyahu Rabba* 3, "אין אהבה אלא תורה", cf. *'Eruvin* 54b and *K'subos* 77b, which understand "אילת אהבים" in *Mishlei* 5:19 as a reference to the Torah).

Comment: כי רחבה היא מיני יםin mishlei

Answer (score 3):

The verse in [Koheles](https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.1.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says:

> (קהלת א ז): "כל הנחלים הולכים אל הים והים איננו מלא",

And on that the [medrash](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Mishlei.10.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says:

> זה התלמוד, שיש בו חכמות הרבה .

Answer (score 1):

**[Bava Kama 82a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=82&format=pdf)**

> דתניא וילכו שלשת ימים במדבר ולא מצאו מים דורשי רשומות אמרו אין מים אלא תורה שנאמר הוי כל צמא לכו למים כיון שהלכו שלשת ימים בלא תורה נלאו עמדו נביאים שביניהם ותיקנו להם שיהו קורין בשבת ומפסיקין באחד בשבת וקורין בשני ומפסיקין שלישי ורביעי וקורין בחמישי ומפסיקין ערב שבת כדי שלא ילינו ג' ימים בלא תורה
>
> For it was taught: ‘And they went three days in the wilderness and found no water, upon which those who expound verses metaphorically said: water means nothing but Torah, as it says: Ho, everyone that thirsteth come ye for water. It thus means that as they went three days without Torah they immediately became exhausted. The prophets among them thereupon rose and enacted that they should publicly read the law on Sabbath, make a break on Sunday, read again on Monday, make a break again on Tuesday and Wednesday, read again on Thursday and then make a break on Friday so that they should not be kept for three days without Torah.’
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/babakamma/babakamma_82.html))

**[Berachot 61b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=61b&format=pdf)**

> תנו רבנן פעם אחת גזרה מלכות הרשעה שלא יעסקו ישראל בתורה בא פפוס בן יהודה ומצאו לרבי עקיבא שהיה מקהיל קהלות ברבים ועוסק בתורה אמר ליה עקיבא אי אתה מתירא מפני מלכות אמר לו אמשול לך משל למה הדבר דומה לשועל שהיה מהלך על גב הנהר וראה דגים שהיו מתקבצים ממקום למקום אמר להם מפני מה אתם בורחים אמרו לו מפני רשתות שמביאין עלינו בני אדם אמר להם רצונכם שתעלו ליבשה ונדור אני ואתם כשם שדרו אבותי עם אבותיכם אמרו לו אתה הוא שאומרים עליך פקח שבחיות לא פקח אתה אלא טפש אתה ומה במקום חיותנו אנו מתיראין במקום מיתתנו על אחת כמה וכמה אף אנחנו עכשיו שאנו יושבים ועוסקים בתורה שכתוב בה כי הוא חייך ואורך ימיך כך אם אנו הולכים ומבטלים ממנה עאכ"ו
>
> Our Rabbis taught: Once the wicked Government issued a decree forbidding the Jews to study and practise the Torah. Pappus b. Judah came and found R. Akiba publicly bringing gatherings together and occupying himself with the Torah. He said to him: Akiba, are you not afraid of the Government? He replied: I will explain to you with a parable. A fox was once walking alongside of a river, and he saw fishes going in swarms from one place to another. He said to them: From what are you fleeing? They replied: From the nets cast for us by men. He said to them: Would you like to come up on to the dry land so that you and I can live together in the way that my ancestors lived with your ancestors? They replied: Art thou the one that they call the cleverest of animals? Thou art not clever but foolish. If we are afraid in the element in which we live, how much more in the element in which we would die! So it is with us. If such is our condition when we sit and study the Torah, of which it is written, For that is thy life and the length of thy days, if we go and neglect it how much worse off we shall be!
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_61.html#PARTb))

Comment: These are good sources to indicate that the Torah is compared to water. But how do you see from these sources that Torah is compared specifically to a ים/sea, as opposed to a river or even just water in general?

Comment: @Binyomin Indeed, you don’t.

Comment: I'm confused- if the question is asking for sources comparing Torah to the sea, and the sources you quote don't make that comparison, then how is this an answer to the question? What is the purpose of sharing this answer? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Torah is always compared to water, here (although not to a sea):

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%90

> ואין מים אלא תורה שנאמר (ישעיהו נה, א) הוי כל צמא לכו למים
>
> Water is always a reference to Torah as it says in Yishaya, "Ho all
> those who are thirsty, come to the water."

However see

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%98

> כִּי מָלְאָה הָאָרֶץ דֵּעָה אֶת יְהוָה כַּמַּיִם לַיָּם מְכַסִּים.
>
> For the world will be full of knowledge of Hashem as the water covers
> the sea

And Malbim (https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Zechariah.13.1?lang=bi)

> וכבר בארנו בפירוש יחזקאל שיש בזה משל ומליצה על התשפטות מי הדעת ונחל
> התורה והאמונה שנמשלו למים
>
> The water of knowledge and the stream of Torah and belief in Hashem (that are compared to water)
> will spread [like the sea].

So the Torah is compared to water, not to the sea. The analogy of the sea refers to the spreading of the water of Torah.